# A function instead of the sibling function

Tags: jquery

I want to know is there a function which can be used instead of the sibling function. I am asking for this because the sibling function requires them to be in the same div for instance and this at times is messing my layout. What function can I use instead? Ill post an example code below.

```
   <div class='hey'> 
   <div class='yes'><button class='my'> </button> </div> 
   <div class='what'> </div>
   </div>


  <div class='hey'> 
  <div class='yes'><button class='my'> </button> </div> 
  <div class='what'> </div>
  <div>
```

I want to slide down the div class What independently depending on where the button is clicked. Any help is appreciated thanks! Please kindly post an example and explain the function cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you could use something like:

```
$('button').click(
    function(){
        $(this).closest('.hey').find('.what').slideToggle();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4sdB6/).

---

**Edited** because I completely forgot to 'explain the function.' Oops.

1. `$('button').click(` selects html `button` elements, and attaches the jQuery click-handler to them.
2. `$(this).closest('.hey').find('.what').slideToggle()` effectively starts at the `this` element (the `button`), moves upwards in the ancestry until it finds the *closest* element that matches the selector that matches the selector-string, an element of class-name `.hey`, and then, within that element's descendants looks for an element of class-name `.what`. After finding this element it `slideToggle()`s its visibility; showing it if it's hidden, hiding it if it's visible.

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).